# Need to put the selected (multiple) RecyclerView item row using checkbox in another Activity with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I need to put the selected (multiple) RecyclerView item row using a checkbox in another Activity which is also using RecyclerView. I have tried a lot to solve the issue but I was not able to find any solution to my problem. So please help me to solve this problem and find a suitable solution.

Thanks!

This is my Adapter.  (From this I need to select multiple RecyclerView item row using checkbox & put in the other one.)

([This is the layout EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXe98.jpg) )

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.text.DateFormat.DEFAULT;


public class sacAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<sacAdapter.MyViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<SAClist> SaCList;
    private List<SAClist> SACListFiltered;

    Double a;
    int b;
    int c;
    Double d;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Double e;
    ViewGroup viewGroup;
    Double value5;

    SAC myActivity;


    private SACAdapterListener listener;
    private DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#############.##");
    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
    private int number = 0;
    private int number1 = 0;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView ProName, Rate, Qty, Total;
        public ImageView thumbnail;
        public Button Qty1, Qty2;
        CheckBox check;
        TextView cartICON;


//        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);


            ProName = view.findViewById(R.id.ProName);
            Rate = view.findViewById(R.id.Rate);
            Qty = view.findViewById(R.id.Qty);
            check = view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            Total = view.findViewById(R.id.Total);
            Qty1 = view.findViewById(R.id.Qty1);
            Qty2 = view.findViewById(R.id.Qty2);
            check = view.findViewById(R.id.check);


            thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    listener.onSACSelected(SACListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });
        }
    }


    public sacAdapter(Context context, List<SAClist> sacList, SACAdapterListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.SaCList = sacList;
        this.SACListFiltered = sacList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent1, int viewType1) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent1.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sac_item_row, parent1, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final SAClist saclist = SACListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.ProName.setText(saclist.getPName());
        holder.Rate.setText("Rate : " + saclist.getPRate());


        String Ra = saclist.PRate;
        double value1 = Ra.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(Ra);
        String TOT1 = holder.Qty.getText().toString().trim();
        final double value3 = TOT1.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(TOT1);

        a = value1 * value3;
        String stringValue35 = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(df2.format(a)));
        holder.Total.setText("TOTAL : " + stringValue35);


        byte[] decoder = Base64.decode(saclist.getPImage(), DEFAULT);


        Glide.with(context)
                .load(decoder)
                .apply(RequestOptions.noTransformation())
                .into(holder.thumbnail);


        holder.Qty1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                number = Integer.parseInt(holder.Qty.getText().toString());
                number++;

                holder.Qty.setText("" + number);

                ////////////////////////////
                String Ra = saclist.PRate;
                double value1 = Ra.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(Ra);
                String TOT5 = holder.Qty.getText().toString().trim();
                value5 = TOT5.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(TOT5);

                a = value1 * value5;
                String stringValue35 = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(df2.format(a)));
                holder.Total.setText("TOTAL : " + stringValue35);

                if (number <= 0) {
                    holder.check.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    holder.check.setChecked(true);
                }


                number1++;
                SAC.update_counter(""+number1);
            }
        });
        holder.Qty2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                number = Integer.parseInt(holder.Qty.getText().toString());
                if (number <= 0) {
                    number = 0;
                } else {

                    number--;


                    holder.Qty.setText("" + number);
                }

                /////////////////////////////////
                String Ra = saclist.PRate;
                double value1 = Ra.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(Ra);
                String TOT = holder.Qty.getText().toString().trim();
                double value2 = TOT.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(TOT);

                a = value1 * value2;
                String stringValue35 = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(df2.format(a)));
                holder.Total.setText("TOTAL : " + stringValue35);

                if (number <= 0) {
                    holder.check.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    holder.check.setChecked(true);
                }

                number1--;
                    SAC.update_counter("" + number1);
            }


        });
//        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                if (holder.check.isChecked()) {
//                    number1++;
//                    SAC.update_counter("" + number1);
//                }
//                if (!holder.check.isChecked()) {
//                    number1--;
//                    SAC.update_counter("" + number1);
//                }
//            }
//        });



    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return SACListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    SACListFiltered = SaCList;
                } else {
                    List<SAClist> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (SAClist row : SaCList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getPName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    SACListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = SACListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                SACListFiltered = (ArrayList<SAClist>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public interface SACAdapterListener {
        void onSACSelected(SAClist sac);
    }




}
```

My Activity

```
package com.i.menu;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SAC extends AppCompatActivity implements sacAdapter.SACAdapterListener {
    private static final String TAG = SAC.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    private List<SAClist> SaCList;
    private sacAdapter mAdapter;
    private SearchView searchView;
    ProgressBar progressBar1;
    TextView cartICON;
    Context context;

    String name, name1;

    private final String URL = "https://.....php/";

    public static TextView counter_value;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sac);

        counter_value = findViewById(R.id.cartICON);


        progressBar1 = findViewById(R.id.progress1);
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toolbar toolbar1 = findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);

        // toolbar fancy stuff
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MENU");

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
        SaCList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new sacAdapter(this, SaCList, this);

        // white background notification bar
        whiteNotificationBar(recyclerView1);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView1.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView1.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL, 36));
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        fetchSAC();
    }

    private void fetchSAC() {


        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch the contacts! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        List<SAClist> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<SAClist>>() {
                        }.getType());

                        // adding contacts to contacts list
                        SaCList.clear();
                        SaCList.addAll(items);

                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error in getting json
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage() +error.getCause());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        APP.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        assert searchManager != null;
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // close search view on back button pressed
        if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    private void whiteNotificationBar(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int flags = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSACSelected(final SAClist sac) {



    }




    public static void update_counter(String value) {
        try {
            counter_value.setText(value);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("Exception", "Exception of type" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class SAClist implements Parcelable {

    String PImage;
    String PName;
    String PRate;


    public SAClist() {
    }

    protected SAClist(Parcel in) {
        PImage = in.readString();
        PName = in.readString();
        PRate = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<SAClist> CREATOR = new Creator<SAClist>() {
        @Override
        public SAClist createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SAClist(in);
        }

        @Override
        public SAClist[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SAClist[size];
        }
    };

    public String getPImage() {
            return PImage;
        }

        public String getPName() {
            return PName;
        }

        public String getPRate() {
            return PRate;
        }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(PImage);
        dest.writeString(PName);
        dest.writeString(PRate);
    }
}
```

New RecyclerView

```
package com.i.menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JUR extends AppCompatActivity implements jurAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    jurAdapter adapter;
    SAClist saClists;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jur);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<SAClist> sacList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("selectedSACList");



        // set up the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new jurAdapter(this, sacList);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Its Adapter

```
package com.i.menu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class jurAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<jurAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    jurAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.jur_item_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }



    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);

        holder.ProName1.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView ProName1, Rate1, Qty1, Total1;
        public ImageView thumbnail1;
        public Button ADD, MIN;


        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
             ProName1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProName1);
//             Rate1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Rate1);
//             Qty1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qty1);
//             Total1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Total1);
//             ADD = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ADD);
//             MIN = itemView.findViewById(R.id.MIN);


//            ImageView thumbnail1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail1);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add selected item's ids to a list. In your second activity you can use this list to create a new recyclerview. New recyclerview has same items as first one. Is that your question?

Comment: (((You should add selected item's ids to a list. In your second activity you can use this list to create a new recyclerview.))).......How should I do that.????

Comment: You should create a new list in order to store selected items in your first activity. On onSACSelected method add selected items to new list. And pass this list to second activity via Bundle.

Comment: Please give me a code so that I can understand            

Comment: Can you share your activity code ? So i can edit your code.

Comment: I added my activity of the corresponding adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215807/discussion-between-kingash-and-ensar-bayhan).

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna try to explain how to do this.

Firstly, change your listener to this;

```
void onSACSelected(SAClist sac, boolean isChecked);
```

Send checked info to activity like this in your onClickListener;

```
listener.onSACSelected(SACListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()), check.isChecked());
```

Create a new list in your activity like this;

```
private ArrayList<SAClist> selectedSACList;
```

Change your onSACSelected method in your activity;

```
@Override
public void onSACSelected(final SAClist sac, boolean isChecked) {
    // You should check list first, if selected items are exist!
    if (isChecked) {
        selectedSACList.add(sac);    
    } else {
        selectedSACList.remove(sac);
    }
}
```

Pass your list to new activity like below;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("selectedSACList", selectedSACList); // You should make your object Parcelable
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your new activity create a new recyclerview and fill your adapter with array list. You can get your list like this;

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<SAClist> sacList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("selectedSACList");
```

Hope it works.. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanyou Very Much, Let me see if it works for me. And I will let you know. :)

Comment: Hi Ensar, How do I add the following    (((ArrayList<SAClist> sacList =bundle.getParcelableArrayList("selectedSACList");))) in the recyclerView

Comment: I also put the implement parcelable in the SACList

Comment: Hi, Once you fill sacList with your data, you can use it to fill recyclerview just like your first activity. You can make sacList variable global to use in your activity. Is that your answer? :)

Comment: Hi, I am still Struggling a lot and how can i put the holder.(whaterver) in the arraylist.

Comment: How can I put the holder.(eg.ProNAme) in the arraylist.

Comment: I think you can use same adapter(sacAdapter) and holder(MyViewHolder) like in your first activity. If you have trouble, just let me know

Comment: Hi, Please help me to put the whole row which is checked into the new RecyclerView. I cant figure out the whole process. Please help meby editing my code. I have put the also put the other RecyclerView too.

Comment: Hi, Ensar Please help me.I have an app which has over 1000 users and I am only 16. I am Just stuck here for past 1 week in this one part. So its my request to you to please help me my just making changes to my code and reply to me. Thanks

Comment: Where is the problem in your code? How can i help you?

Comment: Hi, Can you please make the changes (to make the current RecyclerView be moved to the other one in the different activity) in my code and send it back to me. If you can, it can be great help for me. Thanks

Comment: I can't build and run your code. So, i can't find the problem. If you can explain me the problem or build error, i want to help you.

Comment: Hi, Please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: Hi, Please see the attached screenshot. I have already built the First Page showing all the items. Now when we select the items by checking the check boxes and only these items should be added to the next  layout or recyler view..... Now my issue is that, How do I add only the add the selected item into a new layout or recycler view so that customer can modify/delete the selected item and confirms the order.  If I manage to get to the next layout or recyclerview then I will manage to complete the project  [Link](https://imgur.com/a/HCKqTdO)